# Docker buildkit cache location/size and ID

Tags: docker, dockerfile

There's Docker buildkit: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md
which has an extra option to `RUN` (amongst others): the `--mount=type=cache`.

What I couldn't figure out from the documentation is:

1. where is that cache stored?
2. how can one delete/inspect that?
3. how does buildkit decide what cache goes where? For example if I have the same Dockerfile in two locations, will the caches be the same? What's the key for the cache?
4. the ID option is still ambiguous. If I specify the same ID in different dockerfiles, will they refer to the same cache?

Comment: Really hard to find anything in docs that talks about this

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it is somewhat vague in docker 20.10.5. Could use a pull request or two to update documentation.

1. The `docker` driver cache uses the same storage driver as used for image layers. Metadata is stored in databases at `/var/lib/docker/buildkit`. When docker uses `overlay2` storage driver, the layer is in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/<ID>/diff/`. For `<ID>`, see below. `/var/lib/docker` can vary depending on `data-root` in your `dockerd` configuration. Builders using `docker-container` or `kubernetes` driver keeps the data on a volume.
2. `docker buildx [--builder name] du --verbose` lists build cache. You can also inspect the docker driver caches from `docker system df -v --format '{{ .BuildCache | json }}'`. The cache type `exec.cachemount` is the `RUN --mount type=cache`. You can find the layer using the `ID`, which is not the same as used in `--mount id`. The mount type is implemented by buildkit, so the `docker run --mount` does not recognize it. To get rid of it either `docker buildx prune` or `docker build --no-cache`.
3. The cache key is the value from `id=`. `id` defaults to value of `target`. You need to specify `id` when you need different cache at the same `target`.
4. Yes. They are the same cache regardless of the `target` or Dockerfile. Different builders have their own caches, which keeps for example caches for different architectures separate.

Comment: `To get rid of it either docker buildx prune or docker build --no-cache.` these are two completely different caches.  I don't believe this sentence is correct.  `docker buildx prune` removes the buildkit cache.  `docker build --no-cache` does NOT ignore the buildkit cache.  This is actually quite useful if you want to ensure dependencies are always refreshed, but only downloaded when they change.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipCouling. I had glanced over the code to figure things out, but did not dig into this detail on `--no-cache`. Certainly something to check out in better detail. I think one needs to be careful with which caches you are referring to and with what version of Docker and BuildKit.

Answer (score 0):

For #3 it seems when you don't specify an `id` to the `--mount` option, the same cache will be used, regardless of any other parameters, like the mountpoint or the Dockerfile contents/path.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, it is very useful information. If you want to have separate directories using the same "cache" you can specify an id to prevent issues between two incompatible caches within the system.

https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#run---mounttypecache